# Can you overload the operator new in javascript ? What will it do?

Tags: javascript, function, new-operator

I am trying to make a website work on ie8.

I have found the following js code:

```
var autocompleteAddressController=(function(){
  var my={};
  //...

  my.new=function(val){
    //...
  };
});
```

And in another file:

```
var address = autocompleteAddressController.new("#user_address_name"); 

//...
```

This works fine in recent browsers (chrome and safari)

But it breaks on ie8. I am guessing the the javascript parser of ie8 does not support that we use the reserved name "new" for our custom functions, so in the console I have the error: `expected identifier` on those expressions: `my.new=function` and `autocompleteAddressController.new`.

- Are you supposed to do that ?
- Will it override the `new` operator or just create a function on the object like it's used in my example ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Will it override the `new` operator

No. You cannot override operators in JavaScript.

All the code does is create a method of `my` which happens to have the identifier `new`. This is valid in all environments, but it is only valid to use a reserved word as a property identifier via dot-notation in ES5. You can make it work in IE8 and other non-ES5 environments by using square brackets:

```
my["new"] = function (val) { /*...*/ }

// And in your other file...

var address = autocompleteAddressController["new"]("#user_address_name");
```

---

**Update**

To slightly expand upon this, here are the relevant sections of the ES5 grammar. First, here's the [*Identifier* production](http://es5.github.com/#x7.6):

> *Identifier* ::
>       *IdentifierName* but not *ReservedWord*

Notice that an identifer cannot be a reserved word (`new` is a reserved word). The *IdentifierName* production simply specifies the characters that are allowed in an identifier (with no restrictions based on reserved words).

Here's the grammar for properties in "[object initialisers](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.5)" (object literals):

> *PropertyName* :
>       *IdentifierName*
>       *StringLiteral*
>       *NumericLiteral*

Notice that it refers to *IdentifierName*, rather than *Identifier*. This is the production that allows the use of reserved words as property identifiers.

Finally, compare that production to the one found in the [older ES3 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf):

> *PropertyName* :
>       *Identifier*
>       *StringLiteral*
>       *NumericLiteral*

This time, it uses *Identifier*, and not *IdentifierName*. Since the *Identifier* production disallows the use of reserved words, the code is invalid in ES3 environments.

Comment: You also have to use brackets when you call it, right? e.g. `foo = my['new'](val);`

Comment: @MichaelGeary - Yes, any time you reference it.

Comment: And call it like this: `my["new"]()`

Comment: "All *you* have done". That's legacy code I have in front of my eyes. I would have never try to mess with overloading new before making sure it works. Anyway, I'll give this a try.

Comment: @pinouchon - Sorry, I didn't mean to apply blame, I was just explaining what the code does. Edited.

Comment: I guess it would be easier to just rename, for example, calling it `create` instead of `new` ? (My goal is not to absolutely call it "new", just to make it work on all browsers)

Comment: @pinouchon - Yes, if the code has to run in pre-ES5 environments. If you are writing code that only runs in e.g. Node.js then it wouldn't matter, since it's ES5-compliant.

Comment: I ended up just renaming the `my.new` function to something else, because it was only used as a function like in the example I showed. Thanks for the input.

Comment: JavaScript allows you to overwrite/overload the object operators like `.` or `new` see:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/construct however not supported on dinosaur browsers :(